# C# Threads wont work when i show form with form.ShowDialog

Tags: multithreading, winforms

```
MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

In the MyFormClass

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nameLabel.Text = user.username;
            waitForServerMsgThread = new Thread(() => {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                AddMessage("Start of this thread");
                try
                {
                    stream = client.GetStream();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        AddMessage(client.Available.ToString());
                        if (client.Available > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] byteToRead = new byte[client.Available];
                            stream.Read(byteToRead, 0, byteToRead.Length);
                            MessageToClient message = (MessageToClient)Commands.FromBytes(byteToRead);
                            if (message.messageType == MessageToClient.MessageType.IncoimgMessage)
                            {
                                MessageFromPerson msg = (MessageFromPerson)message.Message;
                                AddMessage(msg.name + " says: " + msg.msg);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    AddMessage("Could not load data from server error " + ex.ToString());
                }
            });
            waitForServerMsgThread.Start();
            FormClosing += (s, args) => waitForServerMsgThread.Abort();
        }
```

And it wont even execute the thread no matter if put `Thread.Start` in _Load or When button is pressed.And no i cant load form with `myForm.Show();` because it wont show it will close after i call it(`ShowDialog()` is called from Thread)

Comment: *ShowDialog() is called from Thread*. Can we see how you create the thread and call *ShowDialog()*?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε if this is more easy for you https://imgur.com/QJx0NUz

Comment: I need minimum code to **reproduce** your problem. As is I can't see your issue.

Comment: I fixed it.Thanks for repsonse